# DotNetNuke Disable search crawler

Tags: dotnetnuke

We are not displaying the Search box on our site.

Can I further disable the Search Site Crawler in Scheduled Jobs to improve performance since I am not displaying the Search box? Will it cause any other impact?

Comment: Looks possible based on [this](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/197/threadid/473882/scope/posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Search Site Crawler in Host > Scheduler if you do not plan to use Search.

Answer (score 0):

On top of disabling I would suggest to clean up the search related tables as well by running the following script:

Delete SearchItemWordPosition
go

Delete SearchItemWord
go

Delete SearchItem
go

Delete SearchWord
go

Delete SearchIndexer
go